# Load javascript after render Dash app Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, plotly-dash

I’m doing a portofolio with Dash plotly,

so, i use a lot of sass and js for making pretty.

but i have a problem.

on my assets/script.js have

```
const menuIcon = document.querySelector('#menu-icon');
const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');

console.log(menuIcon);
console.log(navbar);

menuIcon.onclick = () => {
    menuIcon.classList.toggle('bx-x');
    navbar.classList.toggle('active');
};
```

and get this error:

```
null
null
sripts.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')
    at scripts.js:12:18
```

if i set a timer, works fine:

```
*==== toggle navbar icon =====*/
setTimeout(() => {

    const menuIcon = document.querySelector('#menu-icon');
    const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');

    console.log(menuIcon);
    console.log(navbar);

    menuIcon.onclick = () => {
        menuIcon.classList.toggle('bx-x');
        navbar.classList.toggle('active');
    };
}, 1000);
```

Log:

```
<i id="menu-icon" class="bx bx-menu"></i>
<nav class="navbar"><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a><a href="#about">About</a><a href="#services">Services</a><a hre
```

I think if cuz the js loads first the dash app, which causes no variable to be recognized

So, what i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const menuIcon = document.querySelector('#menu-icon');
  const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');

  console.log(menuIcon);
  console.log(navbar);

  menuIcon.onclick = () => {
    menuIcon.classList.toggle('bx-x');
    navbar.classList.toggle('active');
  };
});
```

Comment: Still doesnt work:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scripts.js?m=1682817834.418762:8:22)

127.0.0.1 - -  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - -  "GET /assets/style.css?m=1682800069.545941 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - -  "GET /assets/style.scss?m=1682800069.5159411 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - -  "GET /assets/scripts.js?m=1682817834.418762 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - -  "GET /_dash-layout HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - -  "GET /_dash-dependencies HTTP/1.1" 200 -
then assets

Comment: it's because the element is not yet loaded when the code is read. Could you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element and try solutions there. If that also does not work, let me know - we can find a solution with checking the element's existence